wzr register usage in main method on ARM
I have this C code :

int foo(){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    return a + b;
}


int main() {
    return 2;
}

After disassembling it shows:
foo():
        sub     sp, sp, #16
        mov     w8, #1
        str     w8, [sp, #12]
        str     w8, [sp, #8]
        ldr     w8, [sp, #12]
        ldr     w9, [sp, #8]
        add     w0, w8, w9
        add     sp, sp, #16
        ret

main:
        sub     sp, sp, #16
        str     wzr, [sp, #12]
        mov     w0, #2
        add     sp, sp, #16
        ret

Why does main method use wzr register on this line str     wzr, [sp, #12] while foo method doesn't?

I'll take guess that you are using clang and running it without optimisations.
Normally when looking at generated code without optimisations, there is lots of seeming superfluous code output and that's the simple answer
Here though, there is more going on.  This is clear to see if we change the source code a bit.
int main2() {
    return 42;
}

int main() {
    return 42;
}

Despite two, on the face of it, identical functions, we see different code output.
main2:
    mov     w0, #42
    ret

main:
    sub     sp, sp, #16
    str     wzr, [sp, #12]
    mov     w0, #42
    add     sp, sp, #16
    ret

This difference is also visible in clang's LLVM IR output, which is the precursor to the generated assembly code.
define dso_local i32 @main2() {
entry:
  ret i32 42
}

define dso_local i32 @main() {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, ptr %retval, align 4
  ret i32 42
}

This difference is highly likely because main is a special function in C.
This answer on stackoverflow explains what makes main special.  Of particular interest is the fact that main doesn't need to have an explicit return statement and, in the absence of one, it is specified in the standard to return zero.
It is highly likely that what is seen in the LLVM IR and assembly language output above is part of clang's preparation to handle this case by setting up a local variable with value zero.
If you compiled with optimisations, the difference will disappear.

Where this gets a little more unexpected is we look at 2 more variations -

main explicitly returns 0
main implicitly returns 0

Consistent with the above, in the first case, clang sets up the %retval variable but doesn't use it.
However, in the second case, and somewhat counter-intuitively, when the code is relying on the implicit behaviour clang skips setting up %retval completely and simply returns a zero directly.
First case -
// main explicitly returning 0

// C

int main() {
    return 0;
}

// LLVM IR

define dso_local i32 @main() {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, ptr %retval, align 4
  ret i32 0
}

// AArch64

main:
    sub     sp, sp, #16
    mov     w0, wzr
    str     wzr, [sp, #12]
    add     sp, sp, #16
    ret

Second case -
// main implicitly returning 0

// C

int main() {
}

// LLVM IR

define dso_local i32 @main() {
entry:
  ret i32 0
}

// AArch64
main:
    mov     w0, wzr
    ret


There are a couple of very similar questions on stackoverflow
here and here
